# Select All checkbox Functionality in Angular Material

Tags: javascript, angular-material

I am binding the values of checkbox to an array and I need to implement a checkbox that selects all the other checkbox when checked.
How can I implement the select All checkbox functionality in Angular material using its tag?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to react on the change of your "select all" checkbox with `ng-change` and modify your array.

```
<md-checkbox ng-model="ctrl.allSelected" ng-change="ctrl.toggleSelection()" />
```

Iterate over the array manually or with [lodash's _.forEach](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/3.10.1/doc/README.md#_foreachcollection-iteratee_identity-thisarg) and set the value in your array.

```
function toggleSelection() {
    _.forEach($scope.content, function (c) {
        c.selected = $scope.allSelected;
    });
}
```